# How to simplify an if statement checking common characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I was wondering if there is a better way of expressing this if statement:

```
if any(i in word for i in '@/#')==False:
```

I am iterating through a list of strings and appending to a new list all of the strings that do not have the above characters (I also want to keep the old list). The above statement works but it is ugly and my IDE is telling me there might be a better way. Is there a way I can sort out the strings I want that is prettier or faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if not any(i in word for i in '@/#'):
```

or

```
if all(i not in word for i in '@/#'):
```

There's almost never a good reason to compare a boolean to `True` or `False` with `==`.

Comment: I don't think I would even say "almost."

Comment: True, "Pythonic" code should rarely resort to comparison against `True` or `False`. Simple `if` or `if not` does the job perfectly well.

Comment: Good to know about avoiding comparing against `True` or `False`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try like this:

```
characters = set('@/#')
```

and then:

```
if characters.isdisjoint(word):
```

or alternatively (but a bit slower, which may be meaningful for extremely long strings):

```
if not characters.intersection(word):
```

<sup>(with a better name instead of `characters` relating to its conceptual meaning of course)</sup>

Comment: Huh. I completely forgot about `isdisjoint`. Given that `'@/#'` is three characters, I'd probably make that the set, and perhaps compute it once at the top of the loop.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that `isdisjoint` will stop immediately when it finds a match, while `intersection` will always go over the whole string.